# How do I mount the OS (system) disk from the UEFI shell?

Tags: shell, mount, uefi

I have to run a firmware update script that lives on the first hard drive of an Intel server board. I must use the UEFI shell to run this script, according to the Intel docs.

(Our servers have no external USB ports, so please don't suggest this.)

I have all the binary firmware blobs including the update script in /moo on blk0.

How do I mount the drive so I can run the script or do I need to mount the drive at all?

Comment: Looks to me like `blk0` is typically a disk rather than a partition?  Based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24372895/886887), mountable partitions should be `fsN` rather than `blkN`   Are there any `fs` devices?

Comment: Nope. No fs devices :(

Comment: Is the server booting via UEFI?  I'd have thought the UEFI boot partition, at least, would be available.

Comment: I have booted into the UEFI shell. I do not know what is mounted. How can I tell?

Comment: Let me rephrase.  Is the main operating system that you have installed on the server configured to boot via UEFI?

Comment: The CentOS installed on our servers is not configured to boot using UEFI.

Comment: You may be stuck then; there probably aren't any FAT file systems for the UEFI shell to access.  Although some server motherboards have an internal slot for a SD card or similar, so you might want to investigate that.

Comment: We found a way to use Intel's sdptool using IPMI to the BMC. This is great because it obviates the need to mess with binaries on the host OS. I have not documented the procedure yet but I hope to post something *somewhere* detailing all the steps. Honestly I don't understand the process well enough to explain yet. It's a **lot** of work and most of it was done by someone else on my team.

Comment: If there are FAT32 file systems, you should be able to access them after a `map -r` and changing to the assigned  'drive', i.e. FS0, FS1, etc.  For other types of file systems such as ext3 or NTFS, you need to first load the appropriate driver if available.

Comment: Did you ever get around to this? This question came up today as an unanswered question.

Comment: No, we didn't need to mount the OS disk. We didn't need to access anything through UEFI to update the firmware.

Comment: "The CentOS installed on our servers is not configured to boot using UEFI." I know this is (now) an old question, but really... you were still using BIOS in 2020?!?

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but just came across this question, when having the same issue. This should mount all disks

```
Shell> map -r
Shell> fs0:
fs0:\>
```

Comment: even if it solves the issue from above, but a support information would be nice

Comment: Feel free to add the support information to your own answer. I have no clue what you mean. This is what worked for me